# Can an unsubscribed user in ExactTarget resubscribe?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have set up a double opt-in list in ExactTarget and a corresponding Web Collect form. If a user correctly subscribes, received the double opt-in mail and gets set to active, but then decides to unsubscribe again, that user remains as status "unsubscribed" in the list database even if the Web Collect form is used again to resubscribe.

Is there a way for a user to resubscribe who changes his mind weeks after unsubscribing?

Comment: Is there a user profile page somewhere?

Comment: What SubAction is being specific for the Web Collect form?  If it is currently set to sub, try sub_add_update instead.  More details: http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/web_collect/

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of it different ways - using web collect or other methods - the full documentation on how to activate is given here:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/unsubscribes/reactivate_subscribers/